# Kohana v .3.0.8 Framework - Dynamically filling the dropdown list based on first dropdown

Tags: ajax, kohana-3

I am using Kohana v 3.0.8 Framework, not very much familiar with Kohana and only a novice with PHP and Javascript.

I am working on a project where I have a Form::select (dropdown list) filled with a list of categories and another select (dropdown list) which needs to be filled dynamically based on which of my categories in the first select (Dropdown list) is selected. So I know I need an "onchange" function, but I am not sure how to include it.

Please can anyone provide me an example on it. How to do it using ajax and kohana?

Your help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is an attributes parameter

`<?php echo Form::select('name', array(),'', array('onchange', 'myFunction()')); ?>`